# excel vba row deletion on column value

Tags: vba, excel

My column 'A' has dates in it. The format is like the following: 20130101

That would be Jan 01 2013. How do I write a macro script to delete all rows that have a date that is a saturday or sunday?

Thank you for your help.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
'Piece together the date.
    dt = Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 7, 2) & "/" & _
         Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 5, 2) & "/" & Left(.Cells(Cell, 1), 4)

    'If the date is a Sat or Sun, delete the row.
    If Weekday(dt) = 1 Or Weekday(dt) = 7 Then
        .Rows(Cell).EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month and day are switched after the date is reorganized. For example, 20130101 was being translated as Jan 01, 2013, but 20130102 was being translated as Feb 01, 2013.

Change this:

```
dt = Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 7, 2) & "/" & _
     Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 5, 2) & "/" & Left(.Cells(Cell, 1), 4)
```

to this:

```
dt = Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 5, 2) & "/" & _
     Mid(.Cells(Cell, 1), 7, 2) & "/" & Left(.Cells(Cell, 1), 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your date format is YYYYMMDD then you can do the following:

```
Sub RemoveSatSun()
    Dim dt As Date
    ' Replace Sheet1 with your own
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        i = 1
        Do Until .Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
            dt = Mid(.Cells(i, 1), 7, 2) & "/" & _
                 Mid(.Cells(i, 1), 5, 2) & "/" & _
                 Left(.Cells(i, 1), 4)

            If Weekday(dt) = 1 Or Weekday(dt) = 7 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
                ' Because we have removed a row, decrement i to ensure we 
                ' don't miss a row since Excel VBA does not have a 
                ' loop continue statement
                i = i - 1
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that I have `i = i -1` when we do remove a row since if we don't we will skip over a row since we increment `i`. From the code you have posted, I believe this was the cause of your issue.

If your date format is different, adjust accordingly as suggested by ARich.

Also in this case you can just call `.Rows(i).Delete` instead of `.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete` but there's no harm with doing the latter either as far as I can see.